# 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable on Openshift

Tags: node.js, git, openshift

Yet another 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable Error it would seem, although I cannot find any responses for this particular log result. Anyway, here's the full error:

Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

I have typed rhc tail nodejs (where nodejs is the name of my app)
and got the following log result:
                ^
    TypeError: Cannot call method 'send' of undefined

```
==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20160119045631 <==
at TCP.onread (net.js:528:27)
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
Tue Jan 19 2016 16:56:31 GMT-0500 (EST): Node server started on 127.8.73.1:8080
...
undefined
Tue Jan 19 2016 16:56:31 GMT-0500 (EST): Node server stopped.
/var/lib/openshift/5694daee89f5cf2eeb00016b/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:107
        resp.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
             ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'setHeader' of undefined

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log <==
TypeError: Cannot call method 'setHeader' of undefined
at ClientRequest.self.routes./ (/var/lib/openshift/5694daee89f5cf2eeb00016b/
app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:107:18)
at ClientRequest.g (events.js:180:16)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1693:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:122:23
)
at Socket.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1588:20)
at TCP.onread (net.js:528:27)
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
Tue Jan 19 2016 19:16:22 GMT-0500 (EST): Node server started on 127.8.73.1:8080
...
undefined
Tue Jan 19 2016 19:16:22 GMT-0500 (EST): Node server stopped.
/var/lib/openshift/5694daee89f5cf2eeb00016b/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:102
        resp.send("<html><body><img src='" + link + "'></body></html>");
             ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'send' of undefined
at ClientRequest.self.routes./asciimo (/var/lib/openshift/5694daee89f5cf2eeb
00016b/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:102:18)
at ClientRequest.g (events.js:180:16)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1693:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:122:23
)
at Socket.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1588:20)
at TCP.onread (net.js:528:27)
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
Tue Jan 19 2016 19:16:23 GMT-0500 (EST): Node server started on 127.8.73.1:8080
...
undefined
Tue Jan 19 2016 19:16:23 GMT-0500 (EST): Node server stopped.
/var/lib/openshift/5694daee89f5cf2eeb00016b/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:102
        resp.send("<html><body><img src='" + link + "'></body></html>");
             ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'send' of undefined
at ClientRequest.self.routes./asciimo (/var/lib/openshift/5694daee89f5cf2eeb
00016b/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:102:18)
at ClientRequest.g (events.js:180:16)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1693:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:122:23
)
at Socket.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1588:20)
at TCP.onread (net.js:528:27)
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
Tue Jan 19 2016 19:16:24 GMT-0500 (EST): Node server started on 127.8.73.1:8080
...
undefined
Tue Jan 19 2016 19:16:24 GMT-0500 (EST): Node server stopped.
/var/lib/openshift/5694daee89f5cf2eeb00016b/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:107
        resp.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
             ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'setHeader' of undefined
at ClientRequest.self.routes./ (/var/lib/openshift/5694daee89f5cf2eeb00016b/
app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:107:18)
at ClientRequest.g (events.js:180:16)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1693:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:122:23
)
at Socket.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1588:20)
at TCP.onread (net.js:528:27)
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
Tue Jan 19 2016 19:16:26 GMT-0500 (EST): Node server started on 127.8.73.1:8080
...
undefined
Tue Jan 19 2016 19:16:26 GMT-0500 (EST): Node server stopped.
/var/lib/openshift/5694daee89f5cf2eeb00016b/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:102
        resp.send("<html><body><img src='" + link + "'></body></html>");
             ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'send' of undefined
at ClientRequest.self.routes./asciimo (/var/lib/openshift/5694daee89f5cf2eeb
00016b/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:102:18)
at ClientRequest.g (events.js:180:16)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1693:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:122:23
)
at Socket.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1588:20)
at TCP.onread (net.js:528:27)
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
Tue Jan 19 2016 19:16:27 GMT-0500 (EST): Node server started on 127.8.73.1:8080
...
undefined
Tue Jan 19 2016 19:16:27 GMT-0500 (EST): Node server stopped.
/var/lib/openshift/5694daee89f5cf2eeb00016b/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:107
        resp.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
             ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'setHeader' of undefined
at ClientRequest.self.routes./ (/var/lib/openshift/5694daee89f5cf2eeb00016b/
app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:107:18)
at ClientRequest.g (events.js:180:16)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1693:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:122:23
)
at Socket.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1588:20)
at TCP.onread (net.js:528:27)
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
```

This would continue until I interrupted, varying between throwing the error `resp.setHeader` and `resp.send`. The code for these two bits are:

```
self.createRoutes = function() {
    self.routes = { };

    self.routes['/asciimo'] = function(req, resp) {
        var link = "http://i.imgur.com/kmbjB.png";
        resp.send("<html><body><img src='" + link + "'></body></html>");
    };

    self.routes['/'] = function(req, resp) {
        resp.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        resp.send(self.cache_get('index.html') );
    };
};
```

For the record, when I push the app onto openshift, the cmd says:

```
remote: Waiting for application port (8080) become available ...
remote: Found 127.8.73.1:8080 listening port
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
```

although it used to get stuck waiting for port 8080 to become available. I had to change some code in server.js (which came automatically when I installed express), from

```
self.initializeServer = function() {
    self.createRoutes();
    self.app = express.createServer();

    //  Add handlers for the app (from the routes).
    for (var r in self.routes) {
        self.app.get(r, self.routes[r]);
    }
};
```

to

```
self.initializeServer = function() {
    self.createRoutes();
    self.app = http.createServer();

    //  Add handlers for the app (from the routes).
    for (var r in self.routes) {
        http.get(r, self.routes[r]);
    }
};
```

Any ideas what might be causing it? Cheers. EDIT:This is the first time I have tried to push my app onto openshift.

Comment: your first log snippet was probably truncated by mistake

Comment: @eis do you mean the log snippet: TypeError: Cannot call method...Debug: Starting child process? Yeah I interrupted the log at a random point since it goes on forever continually saying the same thing

Comment: but it also seems to be cut off from the right? the lines are not complete

Comment: @eis cheers for that, updated now.

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that the method is not defined. As you're using `http` instead of `express`, did you [include it in dependencies](https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-dependency-management.html)?

Comment: @JiriFiala i'm new to nodejs and don't understand what that means! I typed npm install http into the cmd at some point, and it installed it without trouble, and have done http = require('http'). cheers